# Process each comma seperated value in an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to process each row in an RDD with comma separated values. What I am trying to achieve is to set all values close to zero to actual zeros. Here is what I did.

```
   val newRDD = oldRDD
      .map (line => line.split(","))
      .map (line => for(value <- line) {
        if(value.toDouble >= -0.01 && value.toDouble <= 0.01)
            0.toString()
          else
            value
        }
      )
```

All I am getting is just parenthesis () for all rows. Am I making some stupid mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add [`yield`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) keyword, so you will mark that for loop returns list of values:

```
.map (line => for(value <- line) yield {
        if(value.toDouble >= -0.01 && value.toDouble <= 0.01)
            "0"
          else
            value
        })
```

You can read it: for every value from `line` collection, return - `yield` value that: if // etc

You can also use DataFrame API to load Comma Separated file